# How to download videos from YouTube with subtitles?

Tags: download, youtube

How do I download videos from [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/) with subtitles / captions?

I'd tried by using [youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/), with `--write-srt --str-lang` flags but I always get:

> `WARNING: video has no closed captions`.

Comment: Well, does the video have closed captions? I cannot reproduce this issue for videos that have the `CC` sign available. Which video are you trying to download? Does it work with [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3PuHGKnboNY)?

Comment: Yes. Have the `CC` sign. For video that you have posted it worked fine. But for all that I had tried before it does not work, e.g for this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RHy9_RQbrnQ I get:
`WARNING: video has no closed captions` unlike as you can see into youtube page.
`

Comment: See exaclty what I have tried: `python youtube-dl --write-srt --srt-lang en http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RHy9_RQbrnQ
[youtube] Setting language
[youtube] RHy9_RQbrnQ: Downloading video webpage
[youtube] RHy9_RQbrnQ: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] RHy9_RQbrnQ: Extracting video information
[youtube] RHy9_RQbrnQ: Downloading video subtitles
WARNING: video has no closed captions
`

Comment: Quite interesting is to check subtitles with `--list-subs`.

Comment: if you're on a LTS distribution, ensure you use an uo-to-date version of youtube-dl, the TLS apt package on ubuntu:14.04 for example, does not work with generated closed captions, but that current pip release version does (`sudo pip install -U youtube-dl`)

Comment: https://www.4kdownload.com/howto/howto-download-youtube-subtitles I have tested this method, it's work!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Make sure the video you're trying to download has *actual* subtitles uploaded from the owner.

You can then use, for example:

```
youtube-dl --write-srt --sub-lang en 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RHy9_RQbrnQ'
```

There is also an option to download  the automatically generated subtitle files, using `--write-auto-sub`.

See the [`youtube-dl` documentation](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#subtitle-options).

Comment: Is there no way to download the one translated by youtube?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, no. There appear to be some programs for downloading subtitles (like Google2SRT mentioned in the other answers), but those are all for the "real" closed captions.

Comment: This doesn't work as of August 2015, please fix.

Answer (score 9):

If you want a free, easy-to-use program with a simple GUI, there's [Google 2 SRT](http://google2srt.sourceforge.net/en/).

It detects all the available languages and converts to SRT, SSA or SUB.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't convert properly check with this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XJGiS83eQLk

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify *what kind* of subtitles you want to download.

If you want **regular youtube subtitles** in .SRT format (the most widely supported by players) then you would use (assuming you need English subs):

```bash
youtube-dl --convert-subs srt --write-sub -sub-lang en <YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID>
```

If you want **auto-generated youtube subtitles** then you need to use instead:

```bash
youtube-dl --convert-subs srt --write-auto-sub --sub-lang en <YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID>
#                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

To list available subtitle languages use:

```bash
youtube-dl --list-subs <YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID>
```

Once you have identified the languages you want you can request multiple subs with e.g.:

```
youtube-dl --convert-subs srt --write-sub --sub-lang="en,de,es,zh,zh-CN,zh-TW,zh-HK,zh-Hans,zh-Hant" <YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID>"
```