# youtube-dl - download video from YouTube with subtitles - Tutorial

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl

I downloaded Python and youtube-dl, on my desktop I saved the file yt-dl.py. My goal is to download video with subtitles. I opened cmd, wrote cd Desktop, pressed enter, after I dragged the file yt-dl.py on the cmd and then I don't know how download video with subtitles (I only know how download video without subtitles: after dragged file, I enter a space and after the link of video). What command could I use to download video with subtitles?
(In the figure there is a mistake: the file is yt-dl.py instead of yt-dll.py)
[image]

Thank you for your time.

P.S. I tried the command --write-srt --sub-lang en 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RHy9_RQbrnQ' found on [How to download videos from YouTube with subtitles?](https://superuser.com/questions/484665/how-to-download-videos-from-youtube-with-subtitles) but it does not work. The link which I used is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DW5jfjN-5RI&t=1s instead of http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RHy9_RQbrnQ.

---

In the file yt-dl.py there is https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rg3/youtube-dl/2012.02.27/youtube-dl.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the Readme file for youtube-dl (the program you run as the file yt-dl.py), `--write-srt` is not an option, but `--write-sub` is. The Readme file with all options is available here: https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#readme

I successfully downloaded a video with subtitles using `yt-dl.py --sub-lang en --convert-subs srt --write-sub <youtube url>`. `--sub-lang en` chooses english subtitles, `--convert-subs srt` converts the subtitles to the common SubRib (.srt) format, `--write-sub` writes the subtitles to a .srt file and `<youtube url>` is simply the URL/web address of the youtube video page.

An example: `yt-dl.py --sub-lang en --convert-subs srt --write-sub https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sWAN0FwfD5M`

If you use the windows executable, [launch your DOS-prompt](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/chdos.htm), navigate to your youtube-dl.exe file and write e.g: `youtube-dl.exe --sub-lang en --convert-subs srt --write-sub https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sWAN0FwfD5M`. The `--convert-subs` command will not work if you do not have the `ffmpeg` program installed. If that is the case, you have to omit this option and youtube-dl will output .vtt subtitles instead.

Comment: Hi @stalegjelsten, I tried yt-dl.py --sub-lang en --convert-subs srt --write-sub < https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DW5jfjN-5RI&t=1s> and also the same command without <>, but it does not work. The only command which works is yt-dl.py https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DW5jfjN-5RI&t=1s, but this command does not download subtitles.

Comment: Have you installed youtube-dl from https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html? Install the Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable first (https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/confirmation.aspx?id=5555), then download Windows executable (exe) file from the youtube-dl webpage.

Comment: The option `--write-auto-sub` works for me, as mentioned at [this](https://superuser.com/a/484815/571029 "How to download videos from YouTube with subtitles?") answer.

Comment: How to hardcode the subs?

Answer (score 4):

see Subtitle Options (https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/#subtitle-options) and Post-processing Options (https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/#post-processing-options)

My example on fedora 29. `youtube-dl --help (youtube-dl --version 2019.08.13)`

`youtube-dl -ci -f "bestvideo[ext=mp4]"+"bestaudio[ext=m4a]" --write-sub --embed-subs --merge-output-format mp4 --proxy socks5://127.0.0.1:1080/ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=psI7E_J1zPo`

> -c, --continue                   Force resume of partially downloaded files.
>                                        By default, youtube-dl will resume
>                                        downloads if possible.

~

> -i, --ignore-errors              Continue on download errors, for example to skip unavailable videos in a playlist

~

> -f, --format FORMAT              Video format code, see the "FORMAT
>                                        SELECTION" for all the info (requires ffmpeg or avconv installed)

~

> --write-sub                      Write subtitle file

~

> --embed-subs                     Embed subtitles in the video (only for mp4,
>                                        webm and mkv videos)

~

> --proxy URL                      Use the specified HTTP/HTTPS/SOCKS proxy. To enable SOCKS proxy, specify a proper
>                                        scheme. For example socks5://127.0.0.1:1080/. Pass in an empty string (--proxy "")
>                                        for direct connection

~

> --merge-output-format FORMAT     If a merge is required (e.g.
>                                        bestvideo+bestaudio), output to given
>                                        container format. One of mkv, mp4, ogg,
>                                        webm, flv. Ignored if no merge is required

ref:

https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/index.html

https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md

Comment: How to hardcode the subs?

Comment: Hardcoding (as in, burning into the video) is probably beyond youtube-dl's abilities, since it requires reencoding the video. Look towards ffmpeg for that.