# How To Download Youtube Videos With Two Or More Subtitles Youtube-DL

Tags: youtube-dl

I was wondering is there a way to download a Youtube videos with 2 or more Subtitles using Youtube-DL and ignore auto-generated subtitles?

Comment: I'm trying to get 2+ subs of a youtube videos,that tutorial was only for 1 subtitle

Comment: @TimothyRobert `--sub-lang` can take a comma-separated list of language IDs, not just a single one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

> Is there a way to download a Youtube video with 2 or more subtitles using `youtuble-dl` and ignore auto-generated subtitles?

Yes. Use the `--sub-lang` option to specify the subtitle language(s) you are interested in, as implied in the chosen answer to [this Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/1156586/youtube-dl-download-video-from-youtube-with-subtitles-tutorial). Alternatively, you could also use the `--all-subs` option.

> I'm trying to get 2+ subs of a YouTube video, that tutorial was only for 1 subtitle.

Referencing the [official documentation for youtube-dl](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl#subtitle-options), the `--sub-lang` option takes:

> Languages of the subtitles to download (optional) separated by commas, use --list-subs for available language tags

---

**Practical Examples**

Using [this historical K-Drama episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B6xGVEXcj3k) as an example, we can see that there are 6 possible languages for subtitles available (*YouTube Player > Settings > Subtitles/CC*):

- Arabic
- English
- Korean
- Spanish
- Turkish
- Korean (auto-generated)

Using e.g.:

```
youtube-dl --list-subs https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B6xGVEXcj3k
```

Will produce a list of subtitle options, including a list of those specific to the given video:

```
...
hmn      vtt, ttml, srv3, srv2, srv1
Available subtitles for B6xGVEXcj3k:
Language formats
ko       vtt, ttml, srv3, srv2, srv1
es       vtt, ttml, srv3, srv2, srv1
tr       vtt, ttml, srv3, srv2, srv1
en       vtt, ttml, srv3, srv2, srv1
ar       vtt, ttml, srv3, srv2, srv1
```

Note that only 5 relevant options are listed as the `Korean (auto-generated)` subtitles are omitted.

You can then download e.g. English and Spanish subtitles (along with the video) using:

```
youtube-dl --sub-lang en,es --write-sub https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B6xGVEXcj3k
```

To skip downloading the video and get just the subtitles, add the `--skip-download` option e.g.:

```
youtube-dl --sub-lang en,es --write-sub --skip-download https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B6xGVEXcj3k
```

You can even get all 5 available subtitle files at once with the `--all-subs` option:

```
 youtube-dl --all-subs --skip-download https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B6xGVEXcj3k
```

**Converting Subtitles**

Note that YouTube subtitles default to `.vtt` (WEBVTT) format. If you prefer not to have your subtitles in the `.vtt` format, [you can use `ffmpeg` to convert them manually](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/ExtractSubtitles) with e.g.:

```
ffmpeg -i input.vtt output.srt
```

There is also an option to `--convert-subs` automatically with youtube-dl/FFmpeg e.g.:

```
youtube-dl --sub-lang en,es --write-sub --convert-subs srt https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B6xGVEXcj3k
```

However, there are several caveats to converting subtitles:

1. In either case, `ffmpeg` must reside somewhere on your system. You can get Windows builds of FFmpeg from third-parties, such as the [builds kindly provided by gyan.dev](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/).
2. The second automatic option (apparently) [doesn't work with `--skip-download`](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/9073) currently e.g.:

   ```
   # Fail! Subtitles will be downloaded but remain in their original e.g.
   # .vtt format. Confirmed with youtube-dl.exe v2021.05.16.

   youtube-dl --sub-lang en,es --write-sub --convert-subs srt --skip-download https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B6xGVEXcj3k
   ```
3. Finally, while I don't know the source of this problem, `youtube-dl.exe` (2021.05.16) on Windows 10 21H1 (May 2021) did not seem to recognize `ffmpeg` in the System Path for me. Instead, a copy of `ffmpeg.exe` had to be placed directly in the same folder as `youtube-dl.exe` for it to be recognized as present during post-processing (you could also use a symbolic link with a proper file extension [i.e. `ffmpeg.exe`] if you wanted to save some space).